# Validation of fields from some box on the view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have an User model. It has next fields:

```rb
attr_accessible :user_name, :first_name, :last_name, :email ....
```

There is a profile view for the User with 6 blocks. Each of them associated with the various fields. Box 1 - **first_name** and **last_name**, Box 2 - **user_name** and **email**, etc.

I need to validate all the fields (presence, format, etc). But validators must trigger only for those fields, that has came from a particular block (Box 1 or Box 2, for example).

If I write something like next:

```
validates :user_name, :presence => true
```

and I will not edit the block with the *user_name*, I will see the error "user Name can't be blank". I can't use *:allow_blank => true* or nil because it can't(!) be blank!

In two words: I must validate only those fields, that was past from the resquest.

What I can do to solve my problem? Thx

Comment: The problem is not the validations, the validations are there so you will not save a `User` without a name, even if the user did not change it. Can you show your controller code? I want to see how you build your `user` that causes the validation to fail. Normally editing the profile should never invalidate a user.

Comment: user = User.new(params[:user])
if user.save
 redirect_to ...
else
 render :XXX

Answer (score 0):

You can add `if` or `unless` option to skip of particular condition.

```
validates :user_name, :presence => true, :if => "first_name.blank? and last_name.blank?"
```

Comment: I have over 15 fields, and it's sux to write for every field conditions like this one.

Comment: You can pass virtual attribute pass from the form to handle it. Like `validate_block_a` and condition `:if => :validate_block_a`.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but - there are security problem. If it would be some hidden input with the value, associated to the virtual attribute, some user can delete that hidded input and bypass the validation

Comment: Maintain a single variable(`validate_block_a`), then use `if` on block A and `unless` on block B, So it avoid security issue. `validates :block_a_fields, :presence => true, :if => :validate_block_a` and `validates :block_b_fields, :presence => true, :unless => :validate_block_a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the specific fields out of your model and create a model for each block, then you add one_to_one relationships to your User model.

Comment: No no, that is not an solution. I'm only need to validate the fields, that was passed in params of the request (for example only **user_name**). Create separate models and some relationships between them isn't a good idea from my point of view.

Comment: It is a good solution tho. Divide to conquer, did you ever heard about that ? Plus it lowers the size of your tables and optimize your requests.